# Go, Golang : traverse through struct

Tags: go

http://play.golang.org/p/fJACxhSrXX

I want to traverse through an array of structs.

```
 func GetTotalWeight(data_arr []struct) int {
    total := 0
    for _, elem := range data_arr {
        total += elem.weight
    }
    return total
 }
```

But I am getting syntax error

```
   syntax error: unexpected ), expecting {
```

Is it possible to traverse through structs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your function is almost entirely correct. You want to define TrainData as a `type`, and change the type signature of `GetTotalWeight` to `[]TrainData`, not `[]struct`, like so:

```
import "fmt"

type TrainData struct {
    sentence string
    sentiment string
    weight int
}

var TrainDataCity = []TrainData {
    {"I love the weather here.", "pos", 1700},
    {"This is an amazing place!", "pos", 2000},
    {"I feel very good about its food and atmosphere.", "pos", 2000},
    {"The location is very accessible.", "pos", 1500},
    {"One of the best cities I've ever been.", "pos", 2000},
    {"Definitely want to visit again.", "pos", 2000},
    {"I do not like this area.", "neg", 500},
    {"I am tired of this city.", "neg", 700},
    {"I can't deal with this town anymore.", "neg", 300},
    {"The weather is terrible.", "neg", 300},
    {"I hate this city.", "neg", 100},
    {"I won't come back!", "neg", 200},
}

func GetTotalWeight(data_arr []TrainData) int {
    total := 0
    for _, elem := range data_arr {
        total += elem.weight
    }
    return total
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    fmt.Println(GetTotalWeight(TrainDataCity))
}
```

Running this gives:

```
Hello, playground
13300
```

Answer (score 1):

The `range` keyword works only on strings, array, slices and channels. So, no it is not possible to iterate over structs with `range`. But you supply a slice, so that's not a problem. The problem is the type defenition of the function.
You write:

```
func GetTotalWeight(data_arr []struct) int
```

Now ask yourself: what type did I request here?

Everything starting with `[]` indicates a slice, so we deal with a slice of struct.
But what type of struct? The only way to match ever struct would be to use
interface values. Otherwise you'd need to give an explicit type, for example
`TrainData`.

The reason why this is an syntax error is, that the only time the language allows
the `struct` keyword is on defining a new struct. A struct definition has the
struct keyword, followed by a `{` and that's why the compiler tells you that he expects
the `{`.

Example for struct definitions:

```
a := struct{ a int }{2} // anonymous struct with one member
```

Comment: You can iterate over structs using reflect

Comment: You can fetch the struct fields and iterate over them, yes. You can't however simply iterate over structs with `range` and that's the point

Comment: Yup, just posting some extra info for people searching for answers to see